# Prevent __webpack_exports__ from changing to exports when not importing files

Tags: webpack

I'm building files to use on AWS Lambda and bundling them first with Webpack. I noticed some files work (exposing `exports.default`) and some don't. What I found is the files that actually imported other files work while any files that are standalone don't. Here's the meat of each:

## With `import`

```
/***/ (function(module, __webpack_exports__, __webpack_require__) {

"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(__webpack_exports__, "__esModule", { value: true });
/* harmony import */ var __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__external__ = __webpack_require__(1);
/* harmony import */ var __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__external___default = __webpack_require__.n(__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__external__);


exports.default = (event, context, callback) => {
    callback(null, event.name);
};


/***/ }),
/* 1 */
/***/ (function(module, exports) {



/***/ })
```

#### Source

```
import External from './external'

exports.default = (event, context, callback) => {
    callback(null, event.name);
};
```

## Without `import`

```
/***/ (function(module, exports) {

exports.default = (event, context, callback) => {
    callback(null, event.name);
};


/***/ })
```

#### Source

```
exports.default = (event, context, callback) => {
    callback(null, event.name);
};
```

You'll notice the second argument is named `__webpack_exports__` in the first and `exports` in the second which I can only assume is colliding with the actual `exports` the module is attempting to export.

Is there any way to make sure I can actually build these bundles, regardless of if they're standalone files?

I'm using webpack version `3.11.0`.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that adding the following to the output configuration in your webpack config resolves this issue

```
library: '',
libraryTarget: 'commonjs'
```